# Which audio feature is best for text to speech machine learning model?

Tags: python, keras, text-to-speech, librosa

I am trying to create a text to speech model using keras and I have my own data set which has text and only one audio feature .

I want to know which audio feature is best for text to speech. It is my FYP and I am little confused. Currently I am using melspectogram and when I reconstruct it it will produce sound with a little bit noise and bold sound.

Comment: If you work directly with waveforms, then you can skip the reconstruction from spectrogram, which can work much better

Comment: @jon Nordby You mean i just load the wave file in librosa and just use this " s " signal for machine learning directly?

Comment: Yes, WaveNet was the first to show that working, and there has been many works that build on it since